# Python input validity and using asserts

Tags: python, validation, assert

I'm trying to perform good input validity checking on my python code, but I also want it to be succinct.  That is, the solution I **don't** want to go with is this one:

```
def some_func(int_arg, str_arg, other_arg):
    try:
        int_arg = int(int_arg)
    except TypeError, ValueError
        logging.error("int_arg must respond to int()")
        raise TypeError
    try:
        if str_arg is not None:
            str_arg = str(str_arg) 
    except TypeError
        logging.error("Okay, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, bad example")
        raise TypeError
    if other_arg not in (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3):
        logging.error("other arg must be VALUE1, VALUE2, or VALUE3")
        raise TypeError
```

This is just too much code and to much space to spend on just checking 3 arguments.

My current approach is this:

```
def some_func(int_arg, str_arg, other_arg):
    try:
        int_arg = int(int_arg)  #int_arg must be an integer
        str_arg is None or str_arg = str(str_arg)  #str_arg is optional, but must be a string if provided
        assert other_arg in (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3)
    catch TypeError, ValueError, AssertionError:
        logging.error("Bad arguments given to some_func")
        throw TypeError
```

I lose the specificity of my log message, but this is much more succinct and honestly more readable in my opinion.

One thing specifically I'm wondering about is the use of the assert statement.  I've read that it's discouraged to use assertions as a way of checking input-validity, but I was wondering if this was a legitimate way to use it.
If not, is there a similar way to perform this check (or do this validation in general) that's still pretty succinct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could invent a decorator that would validate the arguments for you.

This is how the syntax could look like:

```
@validate(0, int)
@validate(1, str, logMessage='second argument must respond to str()')
@validate(2, customValidationFunction)
def some_func(int_arg, str_arg, other_arg):
    # the control gets here only after args are validated correctly
    return int_arg * str_arg
```

---

This is a naive implementation of the validation decorator factory.

```
def validate(narg, conv, logMessage = None):
    def decorate(func):
        def funcDecorated(*args):
            newArgs = list(args)
            try:
                newArgs[narg] = conv(newArgs[narg])
            except Exception, e:
                # wrong argument! do some logging here and re-raise
                raise Exception("Invalid argument #{}: {}".format(narg, e))
            else:
                return func(*newArgs)

        return funcDecorated
    return decorate
```

Yes, there's a bit of function nesting here, but it all makes sense. Let me explain:

- A decorator is something that takes one function and returns another
- We want `validate(narg, converter)` to be a function that takes some settings and returns a specific decorator (`decorate`) which behaves according to these settings
- `decorate` is then used to decorate a given function (`func`) that takes some positional arguments by creating a new function `funcDecorated` that takes the same arguments as `func` (`*args`) and is written in terms of input function `func` as well as the initial settings `narg`, `conv`.

The actual validation happens inside funcDecorated, which...

- takes the input argument list,
- replaces n-th argument by validating and/or converting it (whatever `conv` does),
- calls the input `func` with the altered argument list.

To do this for several arguments, we apply `validate` multiple times with different arguments. (It's possible to rewrite it to only decorate once, but it looks more clear this way IMO.)

See it in action: http://ideone.com/vjgIS

---

Note that `conv` can act either...

- as a validation function (return whatever it receives, but throw if it's invalid)
- as a conversion function (return the converted value, throw if can't convert)

Note that this implementation doesn't handle keyword arguments.

Comment: On how to implement `validate`: if you like this solution and need any help with writing decorators, let me know and I'll expand on that.

Comment: Though I'm not the question author, I'd be grateful if you expanded your solution. I thought decorators only modify the output of a function.

Comment: Decorators effectively allow to replace one function by another.

Answer (score 2):

Using assertions is perfectly fine for checking arguments validity (type, class or value, that are precisely the things you are checking).

You said:

> One thing specifically I'm wondering about is the use of the assert
>   statement.

So I think [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) can be useful to you.

In particular this part:

> Assertions should *not* be used to test for failure cases that can occur because of bad user input or operating system/environment failures, such as a file not being found.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: have a look at mypy: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
def some_func(int_arg: int, str_arg: str, other_arg):
```

---

[@Vicent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155044/1587329) gave a link to a [great page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) (maybe it's been edited in the meantime). *If you require the check*, it recommends to type-check as follows

```py
from types import IntType, StringType
def some_func(int_arg, str_arg, other_arg):
    assert type(int_arg) == IntType, "id is not an integer: %r" % int_arg
    assert type(str_arg) == StringType or not str_arg
    assert other_arg in (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3), "other arg must be VALUE1, VALUE2, or VALUE3"
```

Good thing about assert is that it shows the line of code where it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [contracts](http://andreacensi.github.com/contracts/) library.
It allows you to declare constraints on function parameters (and even its return values).